# Llamada Ajax me relentiza mi proyecto

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo la siguiente llamada ajax;

```
function notificacion_json(){
    /* Cargar notificaciones_respuesta_solicitudes  */

    var resultado = document.getElementById("span_numero_notificaciones");  
    var xmlhttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){                
            if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
                resultado.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "php/ajax/notificaciones.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send('notificacion_json=' + '1');       
}
```

Esta función la tengo dentro de un `setInterval` que se repite cada 2 segundos, para llamar el archivo `notificaciones.php`;

```
if(isset($_POST['notificacion_json'])){
$usuario_solicitante = $_COOKIE['nombre_usuario'];
$carpeta_destino = $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] . "/intranet/uploads/perfiles/".$usuario_solicitante;
$nombre_archivo = "/metadata.json";
if(file_exists($carpeta_destino)){
    if (file_exists($carpeta_destino.$nombre_archivo)){
        $jsondata = fopen($carpeta_destino.$nombre_archivo,"r");
                //Si el archivo ya existe
                $jsondata = file_get_contents($carpeta_destino.$nombre_archivo); //Leer archivo
                $data = json_decode($jsondata, true); //Decodificandolo para convertirlo en un array asociativo
                echo $data[$usuario_solicitante]['notificaciones'];
        }
}
```

todo funciona perfecto hasta que cierta cantidad de usuarios se conecta (actualmente cuento con mas de 150 usuarios simultáneos) en cuanto implemento esta característica la web se torna sumamente lenta.

Existe alguna alternativa a esto o quizás estoy errado mi código ?

NOTA: El tamaño de la respuesta es de 239b.

> Posible Solución; En vez de que se actualice cada 2 segundos lo he colocado cada 70 segundos, no seria en tiempo real pero funciona y no sobrecarga la red.
>   Me pondré a estudiar Node.js para realizar un sistema a la altura.

Comment: Para implementaciones así tienes que usar otro tipo de acercamiento, como tecnologías push, web sockets, Node.js, donde el servidor manda la notificación y el cliente no tiene que esperar la respuesta de nada, por que definitivamente intervalos en JS no es la respuesta que buscas. El tamaño de la respuesta no es lo que alenta, si no la sobrecarga de peticiones al servidor, (150 cada 2 segundos...)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, buscare una de estas alternativas